# Excel Macro to Find Duplicate in Sheet A and Delete Duplicate in Sheet B

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

This problem involves three Sheets (A, B, C)

Sheet A contains a data table and in Column A has a list of Names

Sheet B contains a data table (Similar not the same as B) and in Column A has a list of Names

Sheet C is a sheet called Name Matching.

I already have a Macro that copies the names in Column A from both Sheet A and B and pastes them in Column A of Sheet C.

There are several duplicates after this is done due to the nature of the data from Sheet A and Sheet B.

Currently I have to manually find the Duplicates in Sheet C and then go into Sheet B and delete the row that has the Duplicate Name.

I would like any formulas that may help solve this. Specifically, a formula that finds the duplicate value on Sheet C and then goes to Sheet B and deletes the entire row of Data.

UPDATE: SEE COMMENT BELOW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposed solution to your updated comment, tested in Excel 2010

```
Private Sub removeDuplicates()

Dim lastCellSheetA As Range, lastCellSheetB As Range
Dim cellA As Range, cellB As Range

'dynamically find the last cell with values
Set lastCellSheetA = Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A1").End(xlDown)
Set lastCellSheetB = Worksheets("SheetB").Range("A1").End(xlDown)

For Each cellA In Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A1", lastCellSheetA).cells
    For Each cellB In Worksheets("SheetB").Range("A1", lastCellSheetB).cells
        'if values are case sensitive, remove the UCase method from both sides of the equality comparison
        If UCase(cellB.Value) = UCase(cellA.Value) Then
            Debug.Print "deleting row " & cellB.Row & " because duplicate value of " & cellB.Value & " found"
            cellB.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next cellB
Next cellA

End Sub
```

Comment: That was awesome. Any further tips on how I can develop skills like that? Here is what I did to solve the problem (Not as clean as yours!!)

Comment: Thanks - If you'll be doing a lot of work iterating through ranges in Excel, I would definitely learn how to effectively use the 'For Each...Next' construct.  
I also learned a lot about Excel specific coding by recording a macro, pointing and clicking my way through some task, then examining the macro.  If my answer worked can you mark it as Accepted (click the check mark next to my answer)? Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

ScreenUpdating = False

```
    FirstItem = Sheets("FTE+Vendor").Range("A2").Value
    SecondItem = Sheets("Vendor").Range("A2").Value

    Offsetcount1 = 0
    Offsetcount2 = 0

        Do While FirstItem <> ""

            If FirstItem = SecondItem Then
                Sheets("Vendor").Select
                Range("A2").Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount2, 0).Select
                Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

                Offsetcount2 = 0
                Sheets("Vendor").Select
                Range("A2").Select
                SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount2, 0).Value

                Offsetcount1 = Offsetcount1 + 1
                Sheets("FTE+Vendor").Select
                Range("A2").Select
                FirstItem = ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount1, 0).Value

            ElseIf FirstItem <> SecondItem Then

                Offsetcount2 = Offsetcount2 + 1
                Sheets("Vendor").Select
                Range("A2").Select
                SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount2, 0).Value

                If SecondItem = "" Then

                    Offsetcount1 = Offsetcount1 + 1
                    Sheets("FTE+Vendor").Select
                    Range("A2").Select
                    FirstItem = ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount1, 0).Value
                    Offsetcount2 = 0
                    Sheets("Vendor").Select
                    Range("A2").Select
                    SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount2, 0).Value

                End If
            End If
        Loop
```

ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub